# GetElementsByTagName not returning elements in webbrowser control

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, getelementsbytagname

I am trying to read HTML source using webbrowser control in C#.

The HTML source contains the following line:

> input class="myclass" name="commit" type="submit" value="Submit"

I am trying to read the above by using following code:

```
HtmlElementCollection buttonElement = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("commit");
```

But it doesn't return any element. I printed buttonElement.Count value and it prints 0.

When I right click in webbrowser control and view source then I can see this element "commit" is there and there is no other element by this name.

Comment: It is an attribute, not an element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's tag name is `input`. Therefore your code should be something like this

```
var element = webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
            .Cast<HtmlElement>()
            .Where(e => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.GetAttribute("name")) &&  e.GetAttribute("name") == "commit")
            .FirstOrDefault();
```